# Закрывается окно поиска CodeBloks C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Есть такое ИДЕ для С++ как CodeBlocks хуже чем визуал студио по удобству и дизайну, но в паре с msys2 очень мощный инструмент который избавляет от многих критических недостатков студии, но у него есть неудобный изъян который вгоняет в ярость если что то нужно в большом коде найти и есть много совпадений. **Проблема заключается в том что пре каждом поиске после нажатия поиск оно находит первый результат и закрывает окно поиска**, если у меня 50 совпадений мне нужно будет 50 раз открыть потиск, иле забить и искать вручную.

**Я не верю что нет настройки которая исправила этот изъян по стандарту, но ее я так и не нашёл, как исправить?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива окну поиска

Вводим туда и кликаем ентер и ничего не закрывается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]